# How to use parameters, request and session objects present in ActionContext?

Tags: java, session, struts2, request, struts-action

Here in this code I am using ActionContext to get Session and ServletActionContext from Request object. I feel this is bad practice, as one must use ActionContext only for Request object.

Is ActionContext's Request object equivalent to the Request object in Servlets ? If yes, how to get request parameters using it ?

```
Map session = (Map) ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
String operatorId = request.getParameter("operatorId");
session.put("OperatorId", operatorId);
// getting hashmap from Bean
analysisNames= slsLoginDetailsRemote.getAnalysisNamesIdMap(); 
// sending map for multiselect
session.put("AnalysisNames",analysisNames);
```

Comment: use request.getParameter("parameter_name");

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Struts2, Session Map and Request Map are wrappers for the underlying HttpServletRequest and Session objects.

If you only need to access attributes, use the wrappers.

Use ActionContext to get them (both the wrappers and the underlying HTTP objects) **only** if you are inside an `Interceptor` or a `POJO`.

If you are inside an `Action`, the best practice is to implement an Interface that will automatically populate your Action's object:

---

To get the ***Request Map wrapper***, [use `RequestAware`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/RequestAware.html)

```
public class MyAction implements RequestAware {
    private Map<String,Object> request;

    public void setRequest(Map<String,Object> request){ 
        this.request = request;
    }
}
```

To get the ***Session Map wrapper***, [use `SessionAware`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/SessionAware.html)

```
public class MyAction implements SessionAware {
    private Map<String,Object> session;

    public void setSession(Map<String,Object> session){ 
        this.session = session;
    }
}
```

To get the underlying ***HttpServletRequest*** and ***HttpSession*** objects, [use `ServletRequestAware`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ServletRequestAware.html):

```
public class MyAction implements ServletRequestAware {
    private javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request;

    public void setServletRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request){ 
        this.request = request;
    }

    public HttpSession getSession(){
        return request.getSession();
    }
}
```

That said, the standard data flow between JSP pages and Actions, or Actions and Actions, is obtained through Accessors / Mutators, better known as Getters and Setters. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

**First**

```
ActionContext's Request object is equivalent to the Request object in Servlets
```

**Second**

If you are using framework like struts. It is a bad practice. You need not create HttpServletRequest objects from ServletActionContext for getting request parameters. Just declare **request parameters** in action class and write getters and setters for them will get  you values in them.

**UPDATE**

If you wanted your request parameter in action class you can do it like this:

```
    public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{
    private String operatorId;
    private Map<String, Object> session;


    //Getter and setters
    public String getOperatorId() {
            return operatorId;
        }

        public void setOperatorId(String operatorId) {
            this.operatorId = operatorId;
        }

@Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
        this.session = session;

    }
    }
```

So now if I wanted to use `operatorId` anywhere all I will do is `getOperatorId()` or use `operatorId` directly. :)

If find implementing `SessionAware` in Action class more reasonable as I can directly access session objects like @Andrea has mentioned..  So now I can directly use `session.put("OperatorId", operatorId);`   and `session.put("AnalysisNames",analysisNames);`

Comment: If i implement the RequestAware interface like shown in the above answer, i can get the request parametres by doung request.get("paramName") ???

Comment: Yes you can.. but you can avoid that implementation if you are writing your logic in Action class. You can avoid RequestAware interface for Action class... See my update for example..