# Using Interceptor to validate user access privilege

Tags: java, struts2, interceptor

I am trying to use an `Interceptor` to restrict users from performing certain actions.

**`ContainsKeyInterceptor`:**

```
public class ContainsKeyInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor implements SessionAware {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Map<String, Object> session;

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
        if(session == null) {
            System.out.println("session is null");
        }

        if(session.containsKey("currentId")) {
            return "index";
        }

        String result = actionInvocation.invoke();

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
        this.session = session;
    }
}
```

It is supposed to redirect the user to the index page if `currentId` is found in the `session`.

However, I am getting a `NullPointerException`, saying `session` is null, as verified by the if-check.

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

    <!-- actions available to guests -->
    <package name="guest" extends="struts-default">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="containskeyinterceptor" class="com.mypackage.interceptor.ContainsKeyInterceptor" />
        </interceptors>

        <action name="index" class="com.mypackage.action.IndexAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="containskeyinterceptor" />
            <result type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
            <result name="index" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="login" class="com.mypackage.action.LoginAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="containskeyinterceptor" />
            <result type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
            <result name="index" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>       
    </package>

    <!-- actions available to members -->
    <package name="member" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="logout" class="com.mypackage.action.LogoutAction">
            <result type="redirectAction">
                <param name="actionName">index</param>
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Why is the `session` null and how to resolve?

([This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_interceptors.htm) was the reference I used.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struts Session is just a `Map<String,Object>` wrapping the underlying `HttpSession`.

While implementing the SessionAware interface [is the correct way to get it in an Action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19540712/1654265), if you want to get it from within an Interceptor, you need to do the following:

To get the Struts **Session Map**:

```
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
    final ActionContext context = ai.getInvocationContext();

    // Struts Session
    Map<String, Object> session = context.getSession();
```

To get the real **HttpSession object**:

```
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
    final ActionContext context = ai.getInvocationContext();

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)context.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);

    // Http Session
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

That said, the reason you are not getting session (nor any other parameter, object and so on) in your Actions, is because you are falling in a common mistake: **applying only one Interceptor** (your) instead of **applying an entire Interceptor Stack** (that should contain your):

You can define it twice in every action:

```xml
<action name="login" class="ph.edu.iacademy.action.LoginAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" /> <!-- this is missing -->
    <interceptor-ref name="containskeyinterceptor" />
```

or, much better, define it once in a custom stack, and use always the stack:

```xml
<interceptors>
    <interceptor-stack name="yourStack">                
       <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
       <interceptor-ref name="containskeyinterceptor"/>
    </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>

<action name="login" class="ph.edu.iacademy.action.LoginAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="yourStack" />
```

and eventually define it with default-interceptor-ref to avoid writing it for every action config of that package:

```xml
<default-interceptor-ref name="yourStack"/>

<action name="login" class="ph.edu.iacademy.action.LoginAction">
```

Comment: Hi Andrea, when do I get the Session Map and when do I get the real HttpSession object?

Comment: Usually you need only the Map.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I used the Session Map and the "define twice" approach, I will experiment now with `<interceptor-stack>`. Upvoted and marked accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/498121/java/java/Dumb-Interfaces) I don't think the interceptor itself can / needs to be session aware.

You can access this property as such:

```
final ActionContext context = actionInvocation.getInvocationContext();  
this.session = context.getSession();
```

There may be a way to get this set automatically, I'm not too familiar with struts2, but it could be that the sessionaware only works for a specific subset of objects and this interceptor isn't one of them for some reason. (not being scanned, being excluded from scan, of the wrong type)

Comment: Hi, I removed all `SessionAware` references in the Interceptor and placed your code inside the `intercept()` method. The `session` is no longer null, but now I am experiencing `NullPointerException` in the [IndexAction](http://pastebin.com/v4z4eafj) class (line 9 - session is null).

Comment: This answered the first question, +1

Comment: By the way, why does it have to be final?

Comment: It doesn't have to be, but it's a good convention to have. Any variable that isn't intended to be changed should be declared final. Basically if you don't define a setter for a variable, and a subclass isn't meant to change it, then declare it final. I particularly do it for any variable that gets set with an initializer and not via a constructor like in this case.