# How to read the full URL from both Interceptors and Actions?

Tags: java, url, servlets, struts2, httprequest

If I typed url as `localhost:8080/MyApp/loginAction.action?username=raj&password=123` how will I get url as it is in interceptor/action class? I tried some methods of request object but not getting. used `request.getRequestURL()`,`request.getQueryString()`....etc

Comment: You can use `param` tag which always adds parameters to the url, unfortunately you can't use it with the `form` tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) to get the full URL excluding the parameters (the `"?foo=bar"` part, that is called QueryString).

You can get the QueryString, if any (and without the `?` sign), with [`HttpServletRequest.getQueryString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29).

---

In an **INTERCEPTOR**, getting the request from the ActionContext:

```java
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {     
    final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext();        
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)context.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);

    String url = request.getRequestURL();
    String queryString = request.getQueryString();

    String fullUrl = url + (queryString==null ? "" : ("?" + queryString));

    LOG.debug(fullUrl);

    return invocation.invoke();
}
```

---

In an **ACTION**, getting the request from [ServletRequestAware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19540712/1654265):

```java
public class MyAction implements ServletRequestAware {
    private javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request;

    public void setServletRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request){ 
        this.request = request;
    }

    public String execute(){
        String url = request.getRequestURL();
        String queryString = request.getQueryString();

        String fullUrl = url + (queryString==null ? "" : ("?" + queryString));

        LOG.debug(fullUrl);

        return Action.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```